# Qt QTextEdit setText for non-latin letters

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qt5.5

I have a string variable and it works with console ,after "setText" non-latin  letters sees "?????????".
utf-8 is enabled.
**example:**

```
string var="афваыва";

    void MainWindow::on_clicked()
    {

        ui->textEdit->setText(QString::fromStdString(var)); //output-?????

        ui->textEdit_6->setText(var.c_str());//output-?????
    }
```

Comment: Does [`QString::fromUtf8`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qstring.html#fromUtf8) help?

Comment: You need to make sure string literals are UTF8 in the first place (although this is default for GCC), then call  fromUtf8 on that string literal, then to print it you need to load a font that supports such language.

Comment: On platforms where default text encoding is not UTF8, you also need to set text coded sometimes.

Comment: Why mix std::string and QString? Just stick with QString and wrap your string literals in [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral). No reason to introduce unnecessary headaches to your code.